# css background full height and 100% width on mobile landscape mode

Tags: html, css, image, background

i am building a landing page, it must be responsive. but i have one small problem. i am having trouble while trying to define the background image. what i want is that on landscape mode the image will take the full width of the device screen but also to be in its full height like in [this example](http://www.strauss-water-campaign.co.il/52667_tami4_per_500K/)

i see that they are using some framework, how can i do it without any framework.
when i try to do it i use `background size:contain`, but it maches the background image to the device screen height.

i have seen some exampels i which an image is placed in the html and it is converted to background image. i think that with `z-index: -9999;`like in the example i gave . but when i try it the image does not go to the background.

Any help would be great

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle with your code? I need something to work with.

Comment: please    https://jsfiddle.net/z1L12opp/    i am starting from screch here. is there a mobile view on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`vh`](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)** and **[`vmax`](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)** to do this.

An example:

**CSS:**

```
#im-full-height {
    background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Philippine-stock-market-board.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: contain;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="im-full-height"></div>
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9d7pavao/)</kbd>

A demo based on your JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/z1L12opp/2/

Comment: thank you very much, this diffidently gets me closer to the solution but the image is cut horizontaly   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3d0pVneiBhScFpERXF4dzMyaUk/view?usp=sharing     what am i doing wrong

Comment: Yes you right, in this case, you must be use `background-size: 100% 100%;   background-position: contain;` See my edit.

Comment: In desktop view, thats image are stretched. Maybe you should use media queries here.

Comment: i use media queries, in desktop view everything is  perfect. but on mobile i cant get it to work

Comment: `vh` will help you in mobile mode. Try with my example, and will work.

Comment: i tried your suggestion, this is the result. http://ari.seveloff.com/mobile.php the image is streached and cut.

Comment: Change the background-size and position to `background-size: 100% 100%; background-position: contain;`

Comment: i did it but on landscape the image is totaly streched  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3d0pVneiBhSLXE1SjAwankwMWM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You will find below the demo of the JSFiddle I created that fits your need. I used new CSS dimension property `vh`, which let the element take X percent of the **V**isible **H**eight.

Refering to the [Can I use website](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) for `vh` property, your code **will not run in IE8** and below, and may probably not work properly in further version.

[editable JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mwo4p44/1/) / [Full screen JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mwo4p44/1/embedded/result/)

**EDIT** : the background follows the scroll

Comment: thank you, but the image gets cut verticaly as i expend the window  https://jsfiddle.net/2mwo4p44/2/,  is there a way to always mantein the full image but also keep the aspect ratio?